# Insert Image in UI in R shiny to cover right half page

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way I can set up the images to cover the right half of the page and keep the left half side of my buttons?

I have know to use img(src='image.png', align = "right"), and save the image in www folder

Comment: Have you tried `fluidRow(column(6, ...), column(6, img(...))`?